# MediaWiki API is returning empty extracts from Wikipedia

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

This page is returning an empty extract:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Alerte%20Rouge%20%28groupe%29&explaintext&rvprop=content&format=json

But the same query works for other pages: 
https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=B%C3%A9rurier_noir&explaintext&rvprop=content&format=json

Adding "&exlimit=max&exintro" as suggested in other topics didn't fix the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On French Wikipedia, "Alerte Rouge (groupe)" is a redirect to "Alerte rouge (groupe)".

Requesting extracts on redirects does not work. Thus you have to use the correct title, i.e. https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Alerte%20rouge%20(groupe)&explaintext&format=json

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to detect when there's a redirect, and get the URL of the correct page in the response?

Comment: Requesting extracts on redirects does work, you just need to use the `redirects` parameter. Compare https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Alerte%20Rouge%20%28groupe%29&explaintext&format=jsonfm with https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Alerte%20Rouge%20%28groupe%29&explaintext&format=jsonfm&redirects.